# Undo region change errors on modded 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, homebrew

I region changed my 3DS a little bit ago and I want to undo it to get eShop access. I also can't update games like Super Smash Bros. to save as well. While running GM9 MegaScript I get the error on line 003 that says:

> 0:/gm9/scripts/GM9MegaScript.gm9
> line 3: too many arguments
> if not find $[GM9IN] NULL
> ("A" to continue)

And line 003 reads:

> if not find $[GM9IN] NULL

I've tried replacing the gm9 folder with the newest one, but it doesn't work. I can't uninstall the CFW because it will brick my system.